# Convert YYYYMMDD to MM/DD/YYYY in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

I need help in figuring out the date conversion logic in Snowflake. The documentation isn't clear enough on this.

In SQL Server, I would try

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '20200730', 101)
```

and it gives me '07/30/2020'.

If I try the following in Snowflake,

```
to_varchar('20200730'::date, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

it gives me '08/22/1970'. Why would it give an entire different date? Need help in getting the logic with the correct date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with what you are doing is that you are assuming that Snowflake is converting your string of `'20200730'::DATE` to `2020-07-03`.  It's not.  You need to specify your input format of a date.  So, 2 options based on your question being a bit vague:

If you have a string in a table and you wish to transform that into a date and then present it back as a formatted string:

```
SELECT TO_VARCHAR(TO_DATE('20200730','YYYYMMDD'),'MM/DD/YYYY');
--07/30/2020
```

If the field in the table is already a date, then you just need to apply the TO_VARCHAR() piece directly against that field.

Unlike SQL Server, Snowflake stores date fields in the same format regardless of what you provide it.  You need to use the `TO_VARCHAR` in order to format that date in a different way...or `ALTER SESSION SET DATE_OUTPUT_FORMAT` will also work.

Comment: Thanks! Marked this as an answer because of detailed explanation what the code is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Try `select to_varchar(TO_DATE( '20200730', 'YYYYMMDD' ), 'MM/DD/YYYY');` which produces `2020-07-30`

You may need to refer to https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html#timestamp-formats